# Unable to share Image of Product in React Native Share

Tags: react-native

I am   working on sharing the product description, url and image using react-native-share. But, it is not working and showing the attachment as somename.null.
I am getting the base64 image from response. Code is written below.

```
shareProduct = () => {
    console.log(this.props.productDetails);
    let { name, product_url, base64 } = this.props.productDetails;

    const shareOptions = {
      title: "Testing APP",
      url: product_url,
      message: "This is the testing. Please check",
      subject: name
    };
    if( base64 !== "" && base64 !== undefined ){
      shareOptions.url = base64;
      shareOptions.type   = 'image/jpeg';
    }
    Share.open(shareOptions)
      .then(res => {})
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Please help me to find issue where I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: In `shareOptions.url`, Are you sharing actual URL or Base64 of image?

Comment: @Rajan Yes, I am getting the response after API call in which I am getting base64 image in jpg format and after that passing it in share option. It's not the images url but it isbase64 format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change url in Options :

```js
    Share.open(
      {
        message: "This is the testing. Please check",
        title: 'Share',
        url: product_url,
        type: 'image/jpg',
        activityItemSources: [
          {
            linkMetadata: {image: `data:image/jpg;base64,${product_url}`},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        // Android only:
        dialogTitle: 'Share',
        // iOS only:
        excludedActivityTypes: ['com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter'],
      },
    );
```

Comment: the above code is not working. I have tried it before.

Comment: use 'image/jpeg' instead of 'image/jpg'

Comment: For me worked "Share.open({message:'Message', url:urifile})..". Keep in mind this: https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open#sharing-a-file-directly